# Block facebook.com using openwrt router

Tags: router, openwrt

I am using OpenWRT router. I need to block a URL or multiple URLs (Not IP) for specific time. for example, I want to block facebook.com so that clients of this router cant access the website. firewall rules should have the option to do that but I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to block by domain name rather than by IP address.

The main reason of why you need such a complicated method is that each domain name (e.g. facebook.com) may be resolved as different IP address at any given time. So, we need to keep a list of resolved IP addresses and add iptables rules based on this list.

First, you should enable logging in dnsmasq config:

```
uci set dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].logqueries=1
uci commit dhcp
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

This will give you log entries like:

```
daemon.info dnsmasq[2066]: reply facebook.com is 31.13.72.36
```

Now, you just have to constantly parse syslog and add corresponding iptables rules like this (note that you most likely need a more versatile script and ipset for better performance):

```
logread -f | awk '/facebook.com is .*/{print $11}' | while read IP; do iptables -I OUTPUT -d $IP -j DROP; done
```

Comment: I have got another option to do that instead of directly accessing iptables.
We can use proxies. tinyproxy might be a good choice.